# Python Oriented Object, QtPy timer

Tags: python, timer

I stuck with my programm, the thing is if I call the function `increase()` my money don't decrease of 1000, but money goes down under 1000. I think I call many times this function, but I am new in OOP and I will be glad if you help me :)

Greetings

```
class Editor(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Editor, self).__init__()
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        self.money = 1
        self.step = 1
        self.counter = 1


        self.ui.click_money.clicked.connect(self.gagner)
        self.loop()
        self.fact = 1



    def _set_fact(self, new):
        self.fact = new

    def _set_money(self, new):
        self.money = new


    def gagner(self):
        self.money += self.step
        self.ui.money.setText(str(self.money))


    def increase(self):

        if self.money > 1000:

            self._set_fact(10)
            self.ui.mine_1.setText("I")
            self.money = self.money - 1000
            self.ui.money.setText(str(self.money))



    def compteur(self):
        self.money += 100 * self.fact
        self.ui.money.setText(str(self.money))
        self.ui.argent_0.clicked.connect(self.increase)



    def loop(self):
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.compteur)
        timer.start(1000)
```

Comment: Why did you use this line(self._set_fact(10)), actually, if you make as _set_fact(1) in this line, the problem seems to be solved